# Flint OS (Chromium) can't set correct time?

Tags: pi-3, chromium, settings

Running Flint on Raspberry Pi 3 and it won't set the time, so obviously I can't access anything because when you browse, the certificates fail. Help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following in terminal to get the time automatically from an ntp server.

```
ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```